# How to compress a pdf with node?

Tags: node.js, pdf, compression

I have found:

- [scissors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scissors)
- [pdfspin](https://github.com/lpatters/pdfspin)

They both rely on [PDFTk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/#download), which costs around $1,000.

Where can I learn more about pdf compression with node, or find the already made library ?

Answer (score 5):

Try using [shrinkpdf](http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/) to compress your pdf file

And this post: [How to run shell script file using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs)

Comment: Yeah this solves the problem perfectly, I would rather our node developers to use shell scripts for such tasks as basic CLI commands. Although its just better when you have test cases and all, saves repeated hassle of typing out commands.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ghostscript4js`:

`gs.executeSync('gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf')`

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/256449/378854) for various options.

Needs to have ghostscript installed on the host system though.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved with [ConvertAPI NodeJS](https://www.convertapi.com/doc/node-library) library:

```
var convertapi = require('convertapi')('<YOUR SECRET HERE>');
convertapi.convert('compress', {
File: '/path/to/my_file.pdf'
}, 'pdf').then(function(result) {
     result.saveFiles('/path/to/dir');
});
```

The compression level can be adjusted by specifying the [image compression algorithms](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-compress#scrollTo=ColorImageCompression) and quality. You can also [remove redundant objects](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-compress#scrollTo=RemoveBookmarks) from the PDF including fonts, bookmarks, annotations, forms, page labels, article threads, tagged information, page thumbnails, layers, duplicates, piece information dictionaries like Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop private data, etc.

You can find a complete list of compression parameters here: [https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-compress](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-compress#scrollTo=ColorImageCompression) and the auto-generated code snippet at the [bottom of the page](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-compress#snippet=nodejs).

*Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.*