# How to run shell script file using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, shell, cassandra

I need to run a shell script file using nodeJS that executes a set of Cassandra DB commands. Can anybody please help me on this.

**inside db.sh file:**

```
create keyspace dummy with   replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':3}

create table dummy (userhandle text, email text primary key , name text,profilepic)
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can execute any shell command using the [shelljs module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs)

```
 const shell = require('shelljs')

 shell.exec('./path_to_your_file')
```

Comment: this isn't serves the purpose. I need to run script file that is present in local system. This module is for executing commands. Could you please tell how to run a shell script file.

Comment: Look into the answer closely. This is a example how to execute a shell script file

Comment: as mentioned in the answer its good to run the bash script using shrlljs instead of running the commands one by one.

Answer (score 160):

You could use "child process" module of nodejs to execute any shell commands or scripts with in nodejs. Let me show you with an example, I am running a shell script(hi.sh) with in nodejs.

**hi.sh**

```
echo "Hi There!"
```

**node_program.js**

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
var yourscript = exec('sh hi.sh',
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
            }
        });
```

Here, when I run the nodejs file, it will execute the shell file and the output would be:

**Run**

```
node node_program.js
```

**output**

```
Hi There!
```

You can execute any script just by mentioning the shell command or shell script in `exec` callback.

Comment: that does not stream the output, use `spawn` instead.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa can you provide an example about this *spawn*

Comment: Exemple here: https://github.com/rollup-umd/build/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: This importation looks cleaner const { exec } = require('child_process')

Answer (score 11):

you can go:

```js
var cp = require('child_process');
```

and then:

```
cp.exec('./myScript.sh', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  // handle err, stdout, stderr
});
```

to run a command in your $SHELL.
Or go

```js
cp.spawn('./myScript.sh', [args], function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  // handle err, stdout, stderr
});
```

to run a file WITHOUT a shell.
Or go

```js
cp.execFile();
```

which is the same as cp.exec() but doesn't look in the $PATH.

You can also go

```js
cp.fork('myJS.js', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  // handle err, stdout, stderr
});
```

to run a javascript file with node.js, but in a child process (for big programs).

## EDIT

You might also have to access stdin and stdout with event listeners. e.g.:

```js
var child = cp.spawn('./myScript.sh', [args]);
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  // handle stdout as `data`
});
```

Comment: This will not work. You cannot require Bash scripts, only node modules.

Comment: @HarryCramer I'm not.

Answer (score 10):

Also, you can use `shelljs` plugin.
It's easy and it's cross-platform.

Install command:

```
npm install [-g] shelljs
```

What is [shellJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs)

> ShellJS is a portable (Windows/Linux/OS X) implementation of Unix
>   shell commands on top of the Node.js API. You can use it to eliminate
>   your shell script's dependency on Unix while still keeping its
>   familiar and powerful commands. You can also install it globally so
>   you can run it from outside Node projects - say goodbye to those
>   gnarly Bash scripts!

An example of how it works:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');

if (!shell.which('git')) {
  shell.echo('Sorry, this script requires git');
  shell.exit(1);
}

// Copy files to release dir
shell.rm('-rf', 'out/Release');
shell.cp('-R', 'stuff/', 'out/Release');

// Replace macros in each .js file
shell.cd('lib');
shell.ls('*.js').forEach(function (file) {
  shell.sed('-i', 'BUILD_VERSION', 'v0.1.2', file);
  shell.sed('-i', /^.*REMOVE_THIS_LINE.*$/, '', file);
  shell.sed('-i', /.*REPLACE_LINE_WITH_MACRO.*\n/, shell.cat('macro.js'), file);
});
shell.cd('..');

// Run external tool synchronously
if (shell.exec('git commit -am "Auto-commit"').code !== 0) {
  shell.echo('Error: Git commit failed');
  shell.exit(1);
}
```

Also, you can use from the command line:

```
$ shx mkdir -p foo
$ shx touch foo/bar.txt
$ shx rm -rf foo
```