# Node JS : invalid data error using execFileSync

Tags: node.js, synchronization

I am stuck on a NodeJS error while trying to execute a script and get the output of it.

I get the following error :

```
TypeError: invalid data
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:623:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:482:20)
    at doRender (/test/apps/application/routes/TEST.js:1786:26)
```

I guess it comes from a misuse of the NodeJS native `execFileSync` function, but I've tried a lot of things to match the [documentation](https://devdocs.io/node~8_lts/child_process#child_process_child_process_execfilesync_file_args_options) without any success so far.

Here is my code :

```
router.get("/stat", authReader, function (req, res) {

    //Current file is in application/routes

    var doRender = function (req, res) {

        var output;

        //I want to execute application/scripts/test.bash

        output= child_process.execFileSync("test.bash",[], {
            cwd: "../scripts"
        });

        result= processDataFromCSV(output);


        //processing data in response
        res.render(acronym + "_test", {
            title: "CSV output",
            result: result,
        });
    }

    doRender(req, res);
}
```

Could you please help me to understand what I am doing wrong ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your `test.bash` is executable, or run it like `/bin/bash test.bash` using `child_process.execSync()`. For more information look at this [answer by Sravan here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44667294/9385541);

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you suggested and ran my script  test.bash using /bin/bash: it worked fine. I am afraid my problem comes from the parameters I give to execFileSync, but, although I keep reading the Node documentation about it, I am still stuck with this issue.