# Execute terminal command on localhost when clicking a HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, bash, server-side

Sorry beginner question.

I would like to execute a terminal command on my local host (Command would be to start a bash script ./test.sh ) upon clicking a button on the HTML webpage.

How do I program this in Javascript to get server side access and execute the script ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Client-side JavaScript can't do this. You will need to write server-side JavaScript (NodeJS) or use another server-side technology (like Java) that can call arbitrary commands. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs/44667294) for an example with NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is not possible in web browser without using server-side approach. You can use [`os.runCommand()`](https://neutralinojs.github.io/docs/#/api/os?id=osruncommandstring-command-function-successdata-function-error) in [Neutralinojs](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs) easily to do above task