# How to provide script specific options in npm python-shell?

Tags: python, node.js, express, npm

I have written a server using Express.js, and I need to run a python script using it. Also I need to provide script specific options like '--imsize 64'. How should I do it?

I have tried using the options argument in PythonShell.run(..). Please guide me through it.

```
/* Some Code */
const ps = require('python-shell');
let imgen_options={
   pythonOptions: ['-imsize 16' ]
};

/* Some more Code */

app.get('/gen-img/:id',function(req, res){
    var data=req.params.id;
    var dataFolder = __dirname + '/dist/generated/'+data;
    ps.PythonShell.run(dataFolder + '/image_gen.py',imgen_options, 
    function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('finished');
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ image: 1 }));
    }); 
});
/* Some more Code */
```

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs) can help you

Comment: @MikeVelazco, I'm trying to run Python scripts, not shell scripts.

Comment: You can do `shell.exec(\`python ${dataFolder}/image_gen.py  ${imgen_options}\`)`

Comment: Yeah, thanks mate... Its a nice workaround.