# Is there a commands for running a local file for a discord bot in discord.js?

Tags: java, bots, discord

I'm trying to create a bot that can run local files on the host computer such as .bat or .exe and can't find commands to run local files.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this thread: [How to run shell script file using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs). This is not a discord.js question but a nodejs question.