# Run cloud shell command in cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

How I can run some gcp shell command (like: `helm install . -n test --namespace=my-namespace -f ./configs/my-conf.yaml`) inside my cloud function?

Comment: Any reason you can't / don't want to use cloud run for this? You can run docker images of choice which should let you run shell commands.

Comment: Yes, architectural reason, I need to use Cloud Functions and helm

Comment: The only way I can think of you can achieve this is to run it through supported programming languages. This thread seems to explain how to run shell commands through nodejs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs

Comment: Howdy Ted ... might you be able to elaborate on "architectural reason"?  I also am sensing a better match to Cloud Run for the described need and would like to understand the architectural need for Cloud Functions over Cloud Run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey have you thought about setting [pyhelm](https://pypi.org/project/pyhelm/) in Python it as a dependency of the Cloud Function and then using it to do what you need via code? Would that work for your use case or am I missing something?

Does pyhelm not let you do the packages installation that you need?

Let us know.