# Trying to run a shell script with node.js using sudo -S

Tags: node.js, shell, webstorm

I'm trying to run a shell script with sudo access which executes a python script using Node.js on Mac. This was a big help [How to run shell script file using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs) but I've gotten stuck:

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -S python [pathToPythonScript]/someScripts.py
```

Node.js code:

```
const shell = require('shelljs');
shell.exec("./[pathToShellScript]");
```

When I run this in WebStorm, I am prompted to enter my password. I do so, but nothing happens; the script isn't executed. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you are not executed the node script with root permissions: `sudo node filename.js`.

Furthermore, it could be that the child process you are spawning with the shelljs module does not inherit the effective UID of the parent node process.
If `sudo node filename.js` does not solve your problem, I would recommend using the `execa` package instead of `shelljs` for better debugging and instrumentation of the spawned child-process: https://www.npmjs.com/package/execa

You can define the `uid`, `gid` of the child process as well as the stdin stream, which you could set to `ignore` such that no interactive prompts can occur (the sudo command would recognize that no `stdin` is provided and therefore not open an interactive prompt).