# use python script in node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

how to call Python functions from my Node.js application to make use of face_recognition library of python, i am new to python environment.
this is my python script

```
import face_recognition

A = face_recognition.load_image_file('C:/Users/shivam/Desktop/facenet/database/x.jpg')
A_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(A)[0]

B = face_recognition.load_image_file('C:/Users/shivam/Desktop/facenet/database/y.jpg')
B_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(B)[0]

 # Compare faces
results = face_recognition.compare_faces([A_face_encoding], B_face_encoding)

if results[0]:
    print('Verified')
else:
    print('Unverified')
```

how to modify it to be a able to use in node.js "child process"

Comment: A general way to call scripts from Node js is mentioned here in another article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs Typically, it's not more involved with a Python script than any other kind of script. kabirbaidhya below however, has good detail on Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way is to use [`child_process.exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to execute your python script and capture the result.

Here's the code you need:

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');

const PYTHON_PATH = '/usr/bin/python3'; // Set the path to python executable.
const SCRIPT_PATH = 'script.py'; // Path to your python script

const command = `${PYTHON_PATH} "${SCRIPT_PATH}"`;

child_process.exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`ERROR: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }

  if (stderr) {
    console.error(`ERROR: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }

  // Do something with the result in stdout here.
  console.log('Result:', stdout);
});
```

**Update the following vars as per your local setup and run it:**

- `PYTHON_PATH` to point to your python executable path and
- `SCRIPT_PATH` to the absolute (or relative) path of your python script.

This would just call the script and capture it's output from stdout.

Suppose, if you have the python script `script.py` defined like this:

```py
print("Hello World")
```

Your node script should output:

```
Result: Hello World
```

Once you get it working, you can replace it with your python script.