# How to execute shell command line when a button is clicked? I know that this question already exist but I couldn't find a solution

Tags: javascript, html, shell

the command line is:
   `imapsync \ --host1 test1.lamiral.info --user1 test1 --password1 secret1 \ --host2 test2.lamiral.info --user2 test2 --password2 secret2`
so I write it in a file script.sh and I gave it chmod +x ...
and now I want it to be executed when I click the button btn1
so what js function should I use x?

Comment: Where would this script be run?

Comment: If you think you can execute shell commands from the browser html then you are wrong my friend; Browsers are *sandboxed* from the host and can't execute commands on it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox on a ubuntu server

Comment: A browser can only connect to a server by http (afaik).

Comment: @evolutionxbox it just a simple shell command like ls or cd that zill be run in background i found something similar with node js I think like this code:

'var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
child = exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
             console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    });
 child(); '

Comment: Yeah. Why not use node to listen to a post/get request (with credentials) which runs you shell script? Make sure to secure the endpoint though.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm a beginner with node js, I don't know what is the exact function should I use.

Comment: Firstly there's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs