# Javascript | Launch CLI Application to Read their Terminal

Tags: node.js

I was wondering if there was a way to launch a console based program with NodeJS and read the output of it (The lines of the console)? I have tried googling this but I get no results at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run shell script file using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs)

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't, I'm not trying to run a shell script file. I am trying to run a C# Console application.

Comment: Oh, I see. Try specifying details like this in your question :) Maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762350/execute-an-exe-file-using-node-js