# Can Cypress execute a shell script in an existing terminal window

Tags: cypress

I must open a terminal in order to login to the Cloud.  That terminal stays open.  The question is can I execute a shell script in that terminal window from Cypress.  I've researched .exec and task, but neither seem like they'd work.  TIA.

Comment: Do you need to login into Cypress Cloud?

Comment: No, not Cypress Cloud.  The real key is I have to have the terminal already opened.  Then send a system command to it which launches a shell script in the opened terminal.  The way I understand it, cy.exec would launch the terminal for you and that won't work in my situation.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility to try is [Cypress Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api#cypressopen).

You would create a Node script and adapt this answer [How to run shell script file using nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647778/how-to-run-shell-script-file-using-nodejs).

The `exec` command opens asynchronously, so you would want to `await` it before invoking Cypress.

```js
const util = require('util')
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec)

async function runShellThenCypress() {
  try {
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('sh login.sh')
    console.log('stdout:', stdout)
    console.log('stderr:', stderr)

    const cypress = require('cypress')
    cypress.open({
      config: {
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
      },
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e); 
  }
}
runShellThenCypress()
```

Answer (score -1):

Cypress executes code in the browser and the browser can't launch ternimal.
Write a script that launches the terminal and opens cypress afterwards